# || operator in arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an issue:

```
    //this console log displays correct value
    console.log('localstorage', localStorage.getItem('subMenu'));
    
    setSubMenu(
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('subMenu') || JSON.stringify(subMenu))
    );
    /*
    this one displays JSON.stringify(subMenu) value, when 
    localStorage.getItem('subMenu') is defined 
    */
    console.log('subMenu', subMenu);
```

I have no idea what's happening. there is value in localstorage (checked with console logs), but somehow JSON.parse is reading second value.

Comment: And what does `setSubMenu()` do?

Comment: State is not updated synchronously. Logging `subMenu` directly after updating it will show you the old value.

Comment: It's not something related to arguments. Using `||` will evaluate to the second operator if the first one is falsy

Comment: Thanks @super it was the right problem!

Comment: Do you really need to stringify when you parse right after it?

Comment: @lupz it's coz I don't want to be subMenu undefined

Answer (score 0):

|| is or operator ... if the result is those bellow,references the one on the right

- undefined
- false
- 0
- '' or null

for example

```js
 let a=null || 45;  //a=45
 let b=12 || 45;  //a=12
```